# putting quote around each word in text using explode

Tags: php

Here I am putting quote around each word:

```
$str = 'my string';
$parts = explode(" ", $str);
echo $parts;
```

Demo : http://ideone.com/2x3DM1

What wrong here?

Comment: Wut? I don't know, what *is* wrong?

Comment: What's wrong here is that you have failed to provide a complete description of what you're trying to do and what the actual problem is. Can you share that with us?

Comment: You are trying to echo out the value of `$parts` which is an array, not a string. If you want one of the values of the `parts` array you need to use the proper syntax: `echo $parts[0]` will echo out the first element in that array.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
function quote($el){
    return '"'.$el.'"';
}

$str = 'this is string';
$array = explode(" ", $str);

for($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++){
    $output = quote($array[$i]);
    echo $output;
}
```

Worked fine for me.